# Where is the motor in the 42082 Rough Terrain Crane box supposed to be?

Tags: piece-information, packaging

The Rough Terrain Crane set (42082) has an outer box with a lot of parts-bags and the 4 wheels in it.
And there is an 2nd inner box with the manuals, the battery-holder and more parts-bags.

I received my set yesterday and did a quick check on the parts-bags but I couldn't locate the motor.
Didn't actually open any of the bags. Will leave that until I'm ready to actually build the thing during the Christmas holiday.

Does anyone know where the motor is supposed to be?
Loose in the inner- or outer-box, one of the parts-bags in the inner-box, one of the bags in the outer-box?

I probably just overlooked it, but knowing where to look for that motor would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTuber *Swedish Brick* put up a nice unboxing video of your set [***here***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIH2S0xtCiA). 
[image]

The motor/battery box seem to be in the white enclosed box, he pulls them both out off camera.
[image]

[image]

[image]

By his video, you will end up with:

- 26 Bags.
  [image]
- <strike>2 Motors</strike>  1 Battery holder, and 1 Motor in a sealed bag.
  [image]
- 4 Wheels.
  [image]
- 4 Rims.
  [image]
- A sealed instructions bag with 1 sheet of stickers, and 2 large manuals.
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: 1 battery holder and 1 motor. The motor is in Bag nr. 10 according to the screen shot. Thank you !!!

Comment: Tsk, tsk...  Never make final conclusions from a still image of a video. Instead, look at the time stamp the snapshot was taken at, and watch the moving video from there.  So, I'll repeat,  according to the video that I watched, these two parts came out of the white enclosed box.  Bag 10 or whatever, just so happened to be in the background.  Yellow Voltron Lion wasn't in a bag either;)  You're very welcomed.

Comment: You are right :-) Bag 10 is in the background. It was hard to tell from the picture and I am at work now. Youtube is blocked here so I can't see the video myself.

Comment: You're fine, Friend.  I have to do some editing and fix the battery holder and motor stuffs.  See ya!

Comment: Found it! Indeed in the inner box, but not in one of the parts bags, but in separate small plastic bag. It was stuck in the corner underneath the manual and I completely overlooked it the first time.